# Need help - logstash crashing with OOM error

Tags: logstash

> Logstash version - 6.2.0
>       OpenJDK

**logstash.yml**

```
pipeline.workers: 8
pipeline.batch.size: 250
pipleline.batch.delay: 5
log.level: warn
path.log : /usr/share/test/logstash
```

It is running in pod in kubernetes with min 4g and max 6g of memory. The 
pod crashes after sometime of usage with OOM error. While analyzing the 
heap found this.

Problem Suspect 1

> 68 instances of "io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor" ,
>   loaded 
>        by "org.jruby.util.JRubyClassLoader @ 0x6c3992e80" occupy 4,364,500,264 
>        (83.46%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

> ```
>    io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3828eb0 - 112,381,328 
>     (2.15%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f63c8 - 108,620,792 
>     (2.08%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817e08 - 100,920,304     
>      (    1.93%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456138 - 100,211,048     
>      (1.92%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456888 - 95,707,344 
>     (1.83%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456820 - 91,473,176     
>     (1.75%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817e70 - 89,591,048 
>     (1.71%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d381a9e8 - 88,260,400 
>     (1.69%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39a9538 - 88,139,568 
>      (1.69%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817c68 - 85,195,688 
>     (1.63%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f3578 - 83,102,248 
>     (1.59%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456750 - 82,410,056 
>     (1.58%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f3510 - 81,845,608 
>      (1.56%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f35e0 - 81,734,736 
>      (1.56%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3923900 - 81,014,544 
>     (1.55%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d381a918 - 80,729,792 
>      (1.54%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d38412d8 - 78,563,144 
>     (1.50%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3840f98 - 77,632,384 
>     (1.48%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39267b8 - 77,357,744 
>     (1.48%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39a8ff0 - 75,636,776 
>     (1.45%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d34566e8 - 75,467,808 
>     (1.44%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39a8f20 - 75,290,592 
>     (1.44%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39a8f88 - 75,134,256 
>     (1.44%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d383e280 - 74,776,152 
>    (1.43%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d34564e0 - 72,343,896 
>     (1.38%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f6228 - 71,541,520 
>     (1.37%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456478 - 71,489,152 
>      (1.37%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f36b0 - 71,307,352 
>     (1.36%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3844878 - 70,976,424 
>     (1.36%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3828e48 - 70,949,224     
>     (1.36%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3844810 - 70,415,992 (1.35%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d34565b0 - 69,949,520 
>     (1.34%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d381a980 - 69,782,704 
>      (1.33%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d381a8b0 - 69,389,880 (1.33%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3841000 - 66,237,624 
>      (1.27%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3926750 - 65,789,608 
>      (1.26%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d34561a0 - 65,720,384 
>      ( 1.26%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39266e8 - 64,684,776 
>      (1.24%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3828de0 - 63,547,248 
>      (1.22%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817b30 - 63,459,752 
>     (1.21%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39a90c0 - 61,840,136 
>     (1.18%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3923968 - 61,683,728 
>     (1.18%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456618 - 61,615,632 
>     (1.18%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817d38 - 60,920,120 
>      (1.16%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817cd0 - 60,482,864 
>     (1.16%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f3648 - 59,936,400 
>      (1.15%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d38449b0 - 58,924,864 
>     (1.13%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d38448e0 - 57,296,960 
>     (1.10%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d381a7e0 - 56,577,712 
>     (1.08%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d39f6290 - 55,650,808 
>     (1.06%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d34567b8 - 55,516,976 
>     (1.06%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3456680 - 54,447,392 
>     (1.04%) bytes.
>      io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3844948 - 53,432,888 
>     (1.02%) bytes.
>     io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor @ 0x6d3817c00 - 52,301,264 
>     (1.00%) bytes.
> ```

Comment: I'd say reduce the number of worker and/or the `batch.size`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html for more information on those parameters.

Comment: This usually happens when we provide workers and batch size. For now, comment on this config and let logstash define himself for worker, batch size,delay. see what values set by logstash and compare

Comment: Reduced both 2 and 100 and still ran into the same issue. The CMS Old gen is never getting garbage collected.  [2019-07-23T10:49:06,985][WARN ][io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap] Failed to register an accepted channel: [id: 0x6f38f4f7, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5044 ! R:/10.123.9.78:51158]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2019-07-23T10:47:46,831][WARN ][io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap] Failed to register an accepted channel: [id: 0xa43358f9, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5044 ! R:/10.123.1.94:35710]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects

Comment: Logstash is keeping the incoming messages in the memory and its not getting garbage collected. is there a setting in logstash that will disable this ?

Comment: can you try increasing the heap size in jvm.options?